# NullPointerException when creating a custom View with onDraw()

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

I'm creating a custom View which I add to a FrameLayout.
When I initialize the view, I get a NullPointerException.
What am I doing wrong. The code for the view is:

```
public class DocumentCameraMask extends View {

    private Context mContext;

    public DocumentCameraMask(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Rect cropRect = new Rect(0,0,800,600);
        canvas.drawRect(cropRect, paint);

        super.draw(canvas);

    }

}
```

The cropRect size will be calculated dynamically and that's why I need to make this view. 
Thanks for your help.

**LogCat**

> 09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   DocumentCameraActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-11 19:13:04.590:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 09-11 19:13:04.590:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-11 19:13:04.590:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-11 19:13:04.590:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4235): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-11 19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):   at
>   android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:332) 09-11
>   19:13:04.590: E/AndroidRuntime(4235):     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3243)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error (see logcat) you get as part of your question.

Comment: can you post logcat here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to override `draw()` method of `View` , whatever drawing stuff you wanted to do, do using `onDraw()` method.

```
public class DocumentCameraMask extends View {

        private Context mContext;

        public DocumentCameraMask(Context context) {
            super(context);

            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Rect cropRect = new Rect(0,0,800,600);
            canvas.drawRect(cropRect, paint);             

        }

    }
```

**refernces:**

**1.** [google link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

**2.** another [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) this might help you

**Updated:**

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DocumentCameraMask mask;
    RelativeLayout rel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
mask = new DocumentCameraMask(this);

        mask.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        byte b = 100;
        int a = b;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Int "+a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

rel.addView(mask);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Custom View DocumentCameraMask class:

```
public class DocumentCameraMask extends View {

        private Context mContext;

        public DocumentCameraMask(Context context) {
            super(context);

            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Rect cropRect = new Rect(0,0,800,600);
            canvas.drawRect(cropRect, paint);             

        }

    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That doesn't make a difference because onDraw calls draw();

Comment: but it is recommended in google android doc, you dont have to change draw() method.

Comment: The Google android documentation is highly outdated and useless. If it were useful, I wouldn't have spent 3 hours trying to solve something so straight-forward. Pardon the venting; in Eclipse, if you try to call onDraw(), it asks you to overwrite draw() which I did.

Comment: As Gru says,you really dont have to override draw(), overriding onDraw() would do the job for you. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Comment: @W.K.S check my updated answer, May be something wrong with your Eclipse.`View` is neither `Abstract class` nor `Interface` so how can eclipse suggest you to `override` the method??.

Comment: Thank you SO SO Much! And sorry for my shirtiness before. Frustrating day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another constructor. Particularly, if you're using this `View` in an XML file, it uses a different constructor, which you're not supplying.

The three constructors for a `View` are:

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)

View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

View(Context context)
```

At a minimum, you should override the second, since this is what is called most often from an XML file. Just make sure you call through to the matching `super()` for each.

---

*Note:*

As Gru says, you really should be overriding `onDraw()`, not `draw()`. I don't know what your Eclipse is telling you, but I've never needed to override `draw()`, and it's never suggested I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
public class DocumentCameraMask extends View {

    private Context mContext;

    /*
    If you ever want to include custom-view manually in code without any layout      attributes,use this constructor.
    */ 

    public DocumentCameraMask(Context context) {
        this(context,null);       
    }

    /*
      If you want to include the custom view in a layout XML file, you need to use this 
      constructor. 
    */ 
    public DocumentCameraMask(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        this.mContext = context;        
    }    


    /*
     If you need to actually do something with the view you have. To do this, you must   override the onDraw method of your custom-View class.
     */

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        /*
          If you want to call the superclass onDraw method (eg.TextView rather than a generic View), then call super.onDraw().If you don't want that, i.e. you are planning to draw the entire View yourself ,there's no reason to call it. If you look at the source code, it shows that View.onDraw() is an empty method. So, calling super.onDraw(), if the parent class is View itself, does nothing. 
         */

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Rect cropRect = new Rect(0,0,800,600);
        canvas.drawRect(cropRect, paint);
    }      
}
```

You can refer [Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

**Note :** As per documentation,

> 1. **public void draw (Canvas canvas)**
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> ```
> Manually render this view (and all of its children) to the given Canvas. 
> The view must have already done a full layout before this function is called. 
> When implementing a view, implement onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) 
> instead of overriding this method. If you do need to override this method,
> call the superclass version.
> ```

```
  2. protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
```

> Added in API level 1
>
> ```
> Implement this to do your drawing.
> ```